# window.location.href or $(location).attr('href') and Polish diacritics

Tags: javascript, jquery, polish

I've got a little problem with my code.
In my website I got a search engine with filter option.
The search condition are kept in window url, 
but the filter in standard does not take the search parameters.

I want to repair this problem.

I wrote simple JS code below:

```
var link = window.location.href;
var elementy = link.replace('+',' ').split('&');
```

So if I have url like this http://mywww.pl/searchcond=&cond1[somePolishCharHere]&cond1

and I use alert to show varible

```
alert(elementy[1]);
```

I expect to see 'cond1[somePolishCharHere]' but I've got 'cond1[someWirdStuffHere]'

Website has set UTF-8 encoding, and for e.q. if i make something like this:

```
var test = [poslishCharHere];
alert(test);
```

I got proper result ([poslishCharHere])

And I have no idea what is wrong...

Comment: you should show the weird characters? Isn't it just some URL encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link = decodeURI( window.location.href );
```

For example

```
decodeURI("http://example.com/?foo=g%C4%99%C5%9B") === "http://example.com/?foo=gęś";
```

Edit: what you see in the browser's URL bar isn't always exactly what a valid URI should look like.
The browser handles it transparently so the user can see readable text and type any character, but the character set in a valid URI is very limited (digits, letters and a few symbols), and everything else needs to be encoded using "percent encoding". https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2